# P&T Dropdown - how to display in Safecracker?

Tags: safecracker

I have a Matrix that contains a P&T Dropdown field. I'm trying to control the markup generated by the Matrix, so I am trying to follow [breaking up a matrix field for use in safe cracker form](http://marcusneto.com/blog/article/breaking_up_a_matrix_field_for_use_in_a_safecracker_form).
Though the example has a `<select>` (I'm assuming it represents a P&T Dropdown), it doesn't show how to loop through its list of options. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did the answer provided work for you?

Comment: No. I added some comments under Derek's response along with some additional information I found (albeit it being a year old).

Comment: I think your solution here is to write a custom plugin that retrieves those options and returns them as variables. Probably more work than is reasonable to expect from an answer here (IMHO). If you're comfortable writing plugins, I could certainly leave an answer that describes the steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the `{options:field_name}` syntax, as [demonstrated in the Safecracker docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#other-channel-fields)?

```
<select name="my_field_name[row_new_0][col_id_14]">
        {options:my_field_name}
                <option value="{option_value}">{option_name}</option>
        {/options:my_field_name}
</select>
```

I'm just not sure it will work with a third-party add-on like PT Select.

Comment: I don't this works because the P&T list doesn't store the item options in the same db field as the native option.

Comment: The {options:field_name} syntax supplied by Derek should work fine for looping through the options - I'm using the exact same syntax for P&T Dropdown fields in SafeCracker forms.

Comment: Thank for the correction, I will have to test it again. The last time I tried it didn't work for me, I may have done something wrong inadvertently.

Comment: @Derek - is `{options:my_field_name}` supposed to be the Matrix field name? Shouldn't I be looping through the Matrix' cell instead? Say I have a Matrix field name `foo` which contains a PT Dropdown cell named `bar`. Is it supposed to be `{options:foo}` or `{options:bar}` or something else?

Comment: Just found this: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/display_p_t_dropdown_options_within_matrix_field_in_a_form. Brandon Kelly says there is no efficient way to do it. The post is over a year old, though.

Comment: Would using the Query mod (and maybe Stash if needed to "transplant") be an option vs hardcoding them like Brandon suggests?

Comment: @Stephen - is your P&T field in a Matrix?

Comment: I've just double-checked and my P&T Dropdown fields that are using Derek's suggested syntax are standalone fields, rather than within a Matrix field. Elsewhere, I have manually broken up a Matrix field that contained a Playa dropdown field, but for this, I used an embed to output the Playa options/entries in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this in a SafeCracker form, but in a [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) form, I've used the [Low Options](https://github.com/lodewijk/low_options) plugin to output the options from a P&T Dropdown field, so it might be worth a try if you're still having trouble with this.