# How to return P&T Dropdown option label within Channel Form

Tags: pixelandtonic, channel-form, pt-dropdown

I'm having trouble returning the option label within a Channel:form tag.

The selected option value returns correctly using {my_drowpdown_field_name}.

However, the option label is not returned using {my_dropdown_field_name:label}.

I'd also like to display a list of possible options using the following:

```
    {options:my_dropdown_field_name}
            <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
    {/options:my_dropdown_field_name}
```

This doesn't seem to be looping through the options. I have tried replacing {option_value} with {my_dropdown_field_name}.

Using EE 2.7.3 and P&T Fieldpack 2.1.1.

Thanks for any help!

edit: just to clarify, {my_dropdown_field_name:label} works fine within Channel:entries tags.

Answer (score 1):

You're prefixing "options" to the field name instead of prefixing "options" with the field name.

i.e. use

```
{my_dropdown_field_name:options}
```

instead of

```
{options:my_dropdown_field_name}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the correct syntax. Just checking here:
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/pt-dropdown-how-to-display-in-safecracker
and here:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/examples.html#more-complex-example

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `{options:my_dropdown_field_name}` syntax is correct only for the built-in EE select fields, not for 3rd-party add-ons.